# Place image on top of element with css

Tags: html, css, css-position

How do I place an image on top of a button with html and css?

```
<div>
  <img src="photo.jpg">
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

I guess it should be something like

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

but it acts a bit weird.

Is it possible to just have a normal div and then set the img to float on top of everything else in the div element?

Comment: When you say, "on top of" do you mean on the y-axis or the z-axis?

Comment: What does "*it acts a bit weird*" mean, in context? How is it 'weird,' what does it do wrong, what does it not do that it should?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your purpose exactly,  if you want the image to take the whole line, make the button lay beneath, why don't set the CSS display attribute of the image to `display:block;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` with `transform: translate()` on img.

This `calc(-100% - 1px)` means

- `-100%` or `- height of element (img in this case)` that you are performing transform on, so it will translate for its own height up on Y axis
- `-1px` is for top border on `div` element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Just to demonstrate if you have border of 5px then you should use `-5px` in calc.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5px));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello see the below one its simple with a few line code

```html
<div style="position:relative;" >
<img src="http://www.industrydynamics.ca/images/skype_icon.png" width="100" height="100"  >

<input type="button" name="" value="Button" style="position:absolute;width:80px;left:10px;top:120px;" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#bottom{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    height:121px;
    width: 984px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

#bottom .content{    
    width: 182px; /*328 co je 1/3 - 20margin left*/
    height: 121px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/182x121"/> 
        <button>Text</button>
    </div>      
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to achieve something like this.

```css
.userIcon {
  background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-128.png') no-repeat;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background-size:20px;
  top: 8px;
}
.left {
  float:left;
}
.right {
  float:right;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
.button{  
  padding:10px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  border:1px solid #07c;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #66bfff;
}
.btnText{
  margin:2px 0px 0px 10px;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="button">
    <span class="left userIcon"></span>
    <span class="right btnText">Create user account</span>
    <span class="clear"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the image to come over the button, you can make the display as block

check the following snippet

```css
div img{
  display:block;
}
button{
  text-align:center;
  margin:40px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-128.png">
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps